# JPA stored procedure: hasMoreResults call many times

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures

JPA stored procedure query:

```
hasMoreResults()
```

will move to the next result? or it can be called many results without any effect?

Comment: Javadoc says return IF THERE ARE MORE. It does not say advance, so no you cannot assume that. You get the NEXT RESULTS by calling `getResultList`.

Comment: JDBC always advance to the next when calling getMoreResult(). I could not find other methods in JDBC to check if there is more results without advancing to the next. JPA depends on JDBC.

Comment: and ? This is not JDBC. There is no `getMoreResults` method. Handling multiple result sets is adequately documented at http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#_generalised_execution_for_multiple_result_sets

Comment: The way to iterate through all result sets is not correct. hasMoreResults() return false for update count. So if update count is between two result sets, the loop will not be able to get the 2nd result set.

Comment: The docs linked are totally correct, and indeed work on all stored procs used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the [specification javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html#hasMoreResults--) doesn't say, so you can't rely on it.

In fact, on [Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d5d3b080f94ca2f498bada7747bbda1e0e3160a2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/ProcedureCallImpl.java) the call *does* advance the ouput pointer:

```
@Override
public boolean hasMoreResults() {
    return outputs().goToNext() && ResultSetOutput.class.isInstance( outputs().getCurrent() );
}
```

While on [EclipseLink](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/7f06ac28cd67cd0f9ac3fa4fdec1449bb9db4ff0/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java), `hasMoreResults` is a private field, that is updated as operations access the resultsets. So calling `hasMoreResults()` has no side effects.

Comment: The JDBC works in the same way, on which JPA depends. Did you know other impl. such as EclipseLink?